# How to create Back End support dashboard for clients in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, backend, dashboard

I have an ecommerce website created using WordPress & WooCommerce. I have to hand over this to a client so that he can have control over the website where he can monitor and update the stock. So, How do I create an Back End dashboard for him as I don't want to give him the access to the default WordPress dashboard where I develop the website.

Answer (score 1):

Make a user account for your client and assign it the role of `Shop Manager` - this will remove all of the backend access that you don't want them to have, whilst giving them full access to the shop's admin.

See: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/roles-capabilities/

Comment: Ok. Will get back to you after trying the same if encountered with any issue. Thanks.